# How to ignore download timeout errors in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm using scrapy 0.24.4

I have set a download timeout to 15 seconds. Some urls take > 15 seconds to download and my log file records these errors. I have many of these exceptions/errors in the log file simply because of the volume of urls I'm crawling and it's becoming hard to see genuine errors. Is there a way to catch these specific exceptions and ignore them?

Comment: Are you getting `Getting %s took longer than %s seconds.` errors in logs and you want to omit them?

Comment: @alecxe - yes exactly

Comment: For what I understand, you would need a custom log observer (example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748222/twisted-log-level-switch)) - then let scrapy know you want to use it, example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942403/how-to-use-scrapy-log-module-with-custom-log-handler). Haven't personally done it though. Hope that at least put you on the right track.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar but I wasn't sure where to start. Thanks for your help, its much appreciated :)